# SQL Server help

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I don't know much about SQL Server or MySQL. I have a web app and I had a friend help develop it so that it could be used to search my database. This database was created in SQL Server 2008 Express. It's only 3 GB. I know there are limitations on this version of SQL Server. I regret not developing for MySQL. Would I really have big issues if my web app was used by many people at once? not that I'm expecting this but I want to know if anyone has a guess on how far I can push it with the limitations of the current version of SQL

Comment: Friends don't install cracked software on someone else's server. Have you asked him what his motivation was? While you're at it ask him if you can store the hotwired car you just stole in his garage.

Comment: @joeqwer: did he edit his question? the answers dont seem to be inline at all with what he's asking.

Comment: Hmm... Don't know but it looks like it.

Answer (score 7):

Since cracked versions can have hidden viruses I recommend then you format the server completely and reinstall the OS and SQL server.  As far as getting in trouble I wouldn't worry too much when you are trying to the right thing -- they give you 30 days to register the legitimate version anyways.

Comment: Couldn't agree more; blast off and nuke it from space, it's the only way to be sure ;)

Comment: +1 Also change any user names and passwords that were in use.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you should be fine.  So long as the copy you are running is valid, licensed, and obtained through a reasonable attempt at legally purchase, you should be ok.

Its the same technical premise as installing a trial copy and then registering it, so long as the latest license action is moving it to licensed status, you're good.

The question of "will I get in trouble" is a much larger legal debate related to EULAs and purchase contracts, probably better fielded by a corporate legal type.

Comment: I don't disagree with the virus concern, especially on a prod database server .. but outside the scope of the "am I licensed" question

Comment: Not so long as the version you are running to do your business is legal, you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, IANAL, but you've done the right thing by uninstalling it. If I were you, I'd relax, I can't imagine for a minute you have anything to worry about. It's your 'friend' who has done wrong, and if he continues this practise he will probably end up in trouble sooner or later.